# Unable to uninstall Wordpress

Tags: boot, 16.04, uninstall, memory-usage, wordpress

I am trying to uninstall wordpress but I encountered the following.
I used the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove wordpress
```

Got the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-92-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
 wordpress-l10n : Depends: wordpress (= 4.4.2+dfsg-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How do fix the issue and uninstall wordpress ?

thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, run `apt-get -f install`

Once you do that, try to uninstall it again: `apt-get autoremove --purge wordpress`

If it still fails, run `sudo aptitude` to try and figure out what the problem is.

Another solution is to do a complete force remove that will remove anything that gets in the way: `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq wordpress`

Comment: The `apt-get -f install` did not work but `sudo aptitude` helped me solve the problem. The /boot memory was full. I cleared it with `sudo apt autoremove` and then uninstalled wordpress. Thanks for the help.